# Is there a reliable way to make Eclipse notice external edits?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on a Mac doing front-end web dev. I'd like to be able to use an external editor, but Eclipse refuses to notice that files have been changed unless I make it the foreground application. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the option "*Refresh using native hooks or polling*" enabled? Find it under **Preferences** > **General** > **Workspace**.

Comment: Yes. Also Refresh on Access. Maybe I need to uncheck that one.

Comment: Update: Unchecking Refresh on Access makes it prompt for refreshment when you make Eclipse the foreground application, but it doesn't affect the other one.